# Cannot reach PowerShell profile

Tags: powershell

I am trying to open PowerShell profile, I typed: `$profile` in Windows PowerShell, and it gave me the following path:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
```

But I don't have the Windows PowerShell folder inside the documents folder when I try to open this path. I go to windows explorer and navigate to Documents folder, but there is no WindowsPowerShell folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the path exists or not using:

```
# Check path of PowerShell profile file
Test-Path $profile
```

If the above returns false, then no profile exists as yet. Use the below command to create a new profile.

```
# Command to create a PowerShell profile
New-Item -path $profile -type file -force
```

Answer (score 0):

Typing `$profile` is not enough to actually create a PowerShell profile.

You can always try to see if a path exist using `Test-Path` and in this case if you try to run `Test-Path $Profile` it would return false, meaning that the path does not exist.

To actually create a profile of yours, you can run `New-Item -Path $profile -Type File -Force`

What this does is basically just creating an empty PowerShell file (.ps1) with a predefined path which PowerShell will execute as soon as you fire it up.

Now if you try to run `Test-Path $Profile` it should return true, and your profile is created.

To open the profile instantly, you can use `Invoke-Item $profile` and from here you can add whatever you like to execute when you fire up PowerShell from your user.